# Canceling datePicker when clicking outside Android

Tags: android, button, android-activity, android-fragments, datepicker

I have a fragment with a calendarView, when I click the button "buttonRectangle", it shows a datePicker to set a date. 
My problem is that if the user cancels (by clicking outside the dialog or with the android back button, the "generateDays()" method is called. I don't want that method to be called if user cancels. I've tried with "setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)" but it doesn't work.

```
buttonRectangle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    generateDays(myCalendar);
                }
            };
            DatePickerDialog dpd= new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            dpd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dpd.show();

            calendar.refreshCalendar();

        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use dpd.setCancelable(true);

Comment: still the same problem.

Comment: solved with this...
if(view.isShown()){
  generateDays(myCalendar);
    }

Answer (score 0):

**try this...**

```
void showDatePicker() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(this);
    datePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay,new OnDateChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    this.monthOfYear=monthOfYear;
    this.dayOfMonth=dayOfMonth;
    this.year=year;
        }
    });
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
    }
    datePicker.setSpinnersShown(true);

    datePickerDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Choose")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                        }
                    }).setView(datePicker).show();


}
```

Comment: this solved the problem...
if(view.isShown()){
  generateDays(myCalendar);
    }